# ChartJS: get points information on hovering the points

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I have successfully got the information by `onClick` function. But is there any method i can get the point information on Hovering over the point. Right now `onHover` as mentioned in docs is not working to get the point. This is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdqkLtc2/6/).

Comment: It's only a typo: you wrote onhover instead of onHover

Comment: @beaver i noticed this is working in v2.7 but i am using 2.6. Other thing is it is alerting on the axis like not on the point but if i drag mouse on the chart. Can you please help me in this regard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In previous versions of Chart.js (for example 2.6) the onHover handler has to be configured as below:

```
  hover: { 
     onHover: function(evt, item) { 
        if (item.length) {
            console.log("onHover", item, evt.type);
            console.log(">data", item[0]._index, data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index]);
        }
     }
  },
```

`itme[0]._index` property points to data of target item

So your fiddle (chart.js 2.6) updated is: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/440L5661/

With chart.js 2.7: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/ttrak7sj/

Comment: oh now i understand but how can i get that point information like the data which is being shown on the tooltip. actually i am overriding the tootltip .

Comment: there is a _index property for item hovered, so data item is data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index]. fiddle updated

Comment: let me check this please.

Comment: How would this work if instead of just 1 dataset, the chart has 2 or more? How would you know over which point is the mouse over?