# Implementing hover callback in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, hover, chart.js

I'm trying to implement a `hover` callback in the chart I made using Chartjs. Here's the part below I'm confused:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        // Am I supposed to put onHover callback inside of hover property of options?
        //hover: {
        //    onHover: (e, elements): void => {}
        //}
        // OR
        // Am I supposed to put onHover callback just as a property of options?
        // onHover: (e, elements): void => {}
    }
});
```

The tricky part is that I've tried the both approach and it works in either way. I've been sniffing around their docs but I seem to not get the right approach. According to their docs, `onHover`: `Called when any of the events fire. Called in the context of the chart and passed the event and an array of active elements (bars, points, etc).` Shouldn't it be called when only `hover` event fires? Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Check this for an example on using onhover: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191984/chartjs-get-points-information-on-hovering-the-points/48194058#48194058

Comment: @beaver Thanks! I managed to hook the `hover`. One question: Say, there are two charts drawn by Chartjs. The feature I'd like to implement is that if I hover on the either of charts, the tooltip would show up on the both charts as if I hover on the both. Since tooltips show up depending on the mouse point, at first I tried to trigger the manual `mousemove/mousemove` event by using `dispathEvent` but it didn't work. And then, I tried to open tooltips programmatically, it didn't work either. How would I implement it?

Comment: I nailed it! Thanks :D

Comment: how? maybe add it as an answer. thanks

Comment: @theprogrammer if you are asking how I implemented it, I dispatched a notification and made other charts subscribe to it and then show the tooltip programmatically. My project is `rxjs` based FYI.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the onHover callback inside the hover options so you can specify your options. The event hover is fire for every other event because they have a hover in them, i.e. the event click, has a hover and then a click.

```
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d'), {
                options: {
                    hover: {
                        mode: 'nearest',
                        intersect: false,
                        onHover: function (e, item) {
                            if (item.length) {
                                const data = item[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index];
                                console.log(item, data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```